# Hello I am new to XAML and I need help. I keep getting this error " The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'Grid'

Tags: xaml

This is my code in xaml.
I keep getting this error " The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'Grid'. Also along with it I get local:AgeValidation - not found. Can you please help. Thank you.

> > ```
> > <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
> >         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
> >         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
> >         Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
> >
> >     <Grid.Resources>
> >         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
> >             <Style.Triggers>
> >                 <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value ="true">
> >                     <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
> >                       Value="{Binding RelativeSource 
> >                      ={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
> >                       Path= (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
> >                 </Trigger>
> >             </Style.Triggers>
> >             <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
> >                 <Setter.Value>
> >                     <ControlTemplate>
> >                         <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
> >                             <AdornedElementPlaceholder>
> >                                 <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"/>
> >                             </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
> >                             <TextBlock Margin=" 3" Text=" *" Foreground="Red" 
> >                                        ToolTip="{Binding Path= AdornedElement.ToolTip,
> >                                                   RelativeSource=
> >                                                  {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
> >                                                  AncestorType={x:Type Adorner}}}"/>
> >                         </DockPanel>
> >                     </ControlTemplate>
> >                 </Setter.Value>
> >             </Setter>
> >         </Style>
> >          <Style TargetType="x:Type Button}">
> >           <Style.Triggers>
> >             <DataTrigger Binding="Binding ElementName= txtAge,
> >                          Path= (Validation.HasError)}"
> >                          Value=" True">
> >                 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value=" False"/>
> >             </DataTrigger>
> >             <DataTrigger Binding="Binding ElementName= txtFirstName,
> >                          Path=(Validation.HasError)}"
> >                          Value=" True">
> >                 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value=" False"/>
> >             </DataTrigger>
> >             <DataTrigger Binding="Binding ElementName= txtLastName,
> >                          Path= (Validation.HasError)}"
> >                          Value=" True">
> >                 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value=" False"/>
> >             </DataTrigger>
> >         </Style.Triggers>
> >     </Style>
> >     <TextBox Name="txtFirstName" Grid.Column=" 1"
> >              Text="{Binding Path=FirstName,
> >                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
> >                             ValidatesOnDataErrors =True}"
> >              Width="150" Margin=" 5"/>
> >     <TextBlock Text="Last Name :" Margin=" 10" Grid.Row="1" />
> >     <TextBox Name="txtLastName" Grid.Column="1"
> >              Text="Binding Path=LastName,
> >                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
> >                             ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
> >              Grid.Row="1" Width=" 150" Margin=" 5"/>
> >     <TextBlock Text="Age : " Margin=" 10" Grid.Row="2" />
> >     <TextBox Name="txtAge" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width=" 150" Margin="5">
> >         <TextBox.Text>
> >             <Binding Path=" Age" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
> >                       ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
> >                 <Binding.ValidationRules>
> >                     <local:AgeValidation MinimumAge="1"/>
> >                 </Binding.ValidationRules>
> >             </Binding>
> >         </TextBox.Text>
> >     </TextBox>
> > ```
>
> ```
>     <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
>             Content=" Update" Margin=" 5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
> </Grid.Resources>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<Grid></Grid>` to be able to insert resources in it !
for AgeValidation make sur that the validation class is public and contained in the specified namespace and inherits the ValidationRule Class see [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-validation-rules).

```
 <Grid>
       <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value ="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                          Value="{Binding RelativeSource 
                         ={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                          Path= (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"/>
                                </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                                <TextBlock Margin=" 3" Text=" *" Foreground="Red" 
                                           ToolTip="{Binding Path= AdornedElement.ToolTip,
                                                      RelativeSource=
                                                     {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                     AncestorType={x:Type Adorner}}}"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
             <Style TargetType="x:Type Button}">
              <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="Binding ElementName= txtAge,
                             Path= (Validation.HasError)}"
                             Value=" True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value=" False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="Binding ElementName= txtFirstName,
                             Path=(Validation.HasError)}"
                             Value=" True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value=" False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="Binding ElementName= txtLastName,
                             Path= (Validation.HasError)}"
                             Value=" True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value=" False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <TextBox Name="txtFirstName" Grid.Column=" 1"
                 Text="{Binding Path=FirstName,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                ValidatesOnDataErrors =True}"
                 Width="150" Margin=" 5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Last Name :" Margin=" 10" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox Name="txtLastName" Grid.Column="1"
                 Text="Binding Path=LastName,
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                 Grid.Row="1" Width=" 150" Margin=" 5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Age : " Margin=" 10" Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBox Name="txtAge" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width=" 150" Margin="5">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path=" Age" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                          ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:AgeValidation MinimumAge="1"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
                Content=" Update" Margin=" 5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid.Resources>  </Grid>`
```